# Android - If else bring image front of text

Tags: android

I have thiscode:

```
boolean showingFirst = false;
            if(showingFirst == false){
                ((View)imageView1.getParent()).requestLayout();
                imageView1.bringToFront();
            }else{
                ((View)textView1.getParent()).requestLayout();
                textView1.bringToFront();
            }
```

Layout

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="247dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="Frame Demo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</FrameLayout>
```

when i click button first it's working

```
((View)imageView1.getParent()).requestLayout();
                imageView1.bringToFront();
```

but i click button second it's not working.

I use one button, when i click first image bring front of, click second textview front of.

Comment: Why are you calling `bringToFront()` at all? If you want to either show an `ImageView` or a `TextView` depending on a button click, it's better to use the `setVisibility()` method instead.

Comment: Because i use one button, when i click frist image bring front of, click second textview front of. Textview large then image , so when image front of text, text still showing

Comment: I believe that you should requestLayout after calling bringToFront

Comment: It not working @jonathanrz

Comment: Faded, both textView1 and imageView1 are inside the same parent? Can you post your xml layout file?

Comment: jonathanrz , i have post in question. Thanks!

Comment: so how i can do? @MikeM.

Comment: yes @MikeM. But else not working

Comment: so how i can do? Please help me @MikeM.

Comment: it not working @MikeM. Else not working